# How do I fix this error ?? "Exception Value: range() integer end argument expected, got float. "

Tags: django, django-views

I couldn't find out the solution of the given error:
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    range() integer end argument expected, got float.
Code is given below:
views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product
from math import ceil
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
print(products)
n = len(products)
nSlides=n//4 + ceil((n/4)-(n//4))
params = {'no_of_slides':nSlides, 'range':range(1,nSlides), 'product': products}
return render(request, 'shop/index.html', params)

def about(request):
return render(request, 'shop/about.html')
```

Comment: are you shure, that error is in that part of code? may be it in your template? this code should run ok. you can try `range(1,int(nSlides))`, but i don't see any sense it should be int already. and why do you need `n//4 + ceil((n/4)-(n//4))`? it should be equal to `ceil(n/4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this line

params = {'no_of_slides':nSlides, 'range':range(1,nSlides), 'product': products}

To

params = {'no_of_slides':nSlides, 'range':range(1,int(nSlides)), 'product': products}

Answer (score 0):

`/` (division operator) returns a float which makes whole calculation a float whereas `range()` function only accepts an integer as a paremeter

You can try the following for a short fix:

```
nSlides=n//4 + ceil(int(n/4)-(n//4))
```

> Note: This can create other logic issues you can fix them by finding alternative solutions.